# Alert Box in YII

Tags: php, yii

How to get an alert box in Yii.

I have a form and after submission I wanted to display an alert box with success message and should then redirect back to my previous page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for native integration, Yii does this by integrating Jquery UI in CJui classes which has a dialog box plugin

You can use it as show below see [CJuIDialog](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDialog) for more details.

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));

    echo 'dialog content here';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

// the link that may open the dialog
echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
));
```

Jquery UI is skinnable with custom css see [Themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/),

However this is old school way of doing dialogs, instead i recommend using [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) either directly or via an extension like [Yii-booster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/) more flexible, and easier to use then CJuiDialog

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing things the way you wanted, I would suggest using the user flash system instead. It makes your user interface cleaner and is the recommended way of handling these types of messages.